# mongoose Model.create hangs with no error messages

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm have a `Referral` model defined and I'm trying to create an instance of this model. However when I do so, the request hangs indefinitely. When I `console.log(Referral)` the object shows in console fine.

Here's my code:

```
                    // TODO: this hangs?
                    console.log("creating referral...");
                    const referral = await Referral.create({
                        referrer: referrer.email,
                        referee: user.email,
                        amount: 1000,
                    });
                    console.log("referral created");
```

Notice that `referral created` is never actually printed to the console!

Here's the model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        referrer: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },

        referee: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },

        // Number of cents, 1000 = $10
        amount: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            min: 0,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

// A user can't refer the same user twice
schema.index({ referrer: 1, referee: 1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Referral", schema);
```

After removing the `schema.index` line, there was no change. I've also tried checking if I'm using `connectionOpen`, with mongoose, but I'm not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I migrated the `Referral` model to use the type of `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` rather than `string`. But I kept trying to pass `referrer.email` as the argument for those fields.

After changing my code like so, it no longer hangs.

```
                    const referral = await Referral.create({
                        referrer: referrer,
                        referee: user,
                        amount: 1000,
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**I had a similar problem and here is how I solved it**

I was trying to create a new user in my Node.js application. I was using the mongoose-sequence plugin to automatically increment the user ID. However, I imported the plugin incorrectly, which caused the create() method to hang.

The problem was that the plugin was not being initialized correctly. This meant that the create() method was waiting for the plugin to finish initializing, which was never going to happen because the plugin was not being imported correctly.

The code worked perfectly immediately I commented the plugin out.

**Make sure you are not forgetting the await Keyword**

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of @Mahmud,
If you're using mongoose-sequence with mongoose, mongoose@7.0.0 dropped the callback supports for lots of model functions and mongoose-sequence utilizes one/more such callbacks.
More here: https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence/issues/133